# Check values precedence based on creation date order in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a small case that I want to highlight using SQL/Snowflake.

For example (table 1 below), if the creation date of the value `NO PO` in `CF_PO_Number` is less than the creation date of the value `PO-0257880` then `PO_Issued = True`

| Job_ID | CF_PO_Number | Created_At |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 153428 | PO-025780 | 2021-10-20 10:22:43.000000000 |
| 153428 |  | 2021-10-20 09:03:14.000000000 |
| 153428 | NO PO | 2021-10-05 13:16:04.000000000 |

The desired outcome for table 1 is as follows,

| Job_ID | PO_Issued |
| --- | --- |
| 153428 | True |

Another example (table 2 below), if the creation date of the value `PO-0257880` in `CF_PO_Number` is older than the creation date of the value `NO PO` then `PO_Issued = False`

| Job_ID | CF_PO_Number | Created_At |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 153428 | NO PO | 2021-10-20 10:22:43.000000000 |
| 153428 |  | 2021-10-20 09:03:14.000000000 |
| 153428 | PO-025780 | 2021-10-05 13:16:04.000000000 |

The desired outcome for table 2 is as follows,

| Job_ID | PO_Issued |
| --- | --- |
| 153428 | False |

Moreover, `CF_PO_Number` can have only one value either `NO PO` and it means `PO is required and not issued` then `PO_Issued = False` or `PO-025780` which means `PO is required and issued` then `PO_Issued = True`, the example cases are rarely happening.

I hope the case is now clear.

Comment: So what is your problem? What are trying to mark/classify in the data? Are you trying to remove rows? Also avoid posting pictures for data that can be put in a table: and what is the input and desired output? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow

Comment: Understood - will edit the post rn

Comment: I edited the post and included all tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand there can only be three values of `CF_PO_Number` `['NO_PO', 'PO-025780', null]` and we are finding the related dates for no_po and po.

Then this SQL I think covers your cases:
just noticed the 431 case

```
SELECT
    job_id,
    max(iff(CF_PO_Number='NO PO', Created_At, null)) as no_po_date,
    max(iff(CF_PO_Number='PO-025780', Created_At, null)) as po_date,
    CASE
        WHEN no_po_date is null AND po_date is not null then true
        WHEN no_po_date is not null AND po_date is null then false
        WHEN no_po_date is null AND po_date is null then false -- CAN THIS HAPPEN? 
        ELSE no_po_date < po_date
    END as PO_Issued      
FROM VALUES
    (153428, 'PO-025780', '2021-10-20 10:22:43'),
    (153428, null, '2021-10-20 09:03:14'),
    (153428, 'NO PO', '2021-10-05 13:16:04'),
    (153429, 'NO PO', '2021-10-20 10:22:43'),
    (153429, null, '2021-10-20 09:03:14'),
    (153429, 'PO-025780', '2021-10-05 13:16:04'),
    (153430, 'NO PO', '2021-10-05 13:16:04'),
    (153431, 'PO-025780', '2021-10-05 13:16:04')
    t(Job_ID, CF_PO_Number, Created_At)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

which gives:

| JOB_ID | NO_PO_DATE | PO_DATE | PO_ISSUED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 153,428 | 2021-10-05 13:16:04 | 2021-10-20 10:22:43 | TRUE |
| 153,429 | 2021-10-20 10:22:43 | 2021-10-05 13:16:04 | FALSE |
| 153,430 | 2021-10-05 13:16:04 |  | FALSE |
| 153,431 |  | 2021-10-05 13:16:04 | TRUE |

Comment: And to answer your question - yes it can happen and we need to highlight this in the case as well.

Comment: @Nabaa by "highlight" do you mean 'true' or trigger some other flag. Not that it almost matters, but it seems a puzzling combination of triggering states

Comment: No it should be false, for example if no po date and po date are nulls then it means this job required part order and it was issued using ERP system but the integration failed.